# STUFF function equivalent in netezza

Tags: netezza

whats the STUFF equivalent in netezza,  I am trying to do rows to column concatenation. I tried the GROUP_CONCAT()/ String_AGG as mentioned in the other question but i am not able to use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used STUFF before, but looking at the description, there is not a native Netezza function that is its equivalent.  However, it *seems* a simple thing to recreate with SUBSTR.  Since I don't really use STUFF, take this with a grain of salt, but give it a try.

If we take an example of using STUFF:

```
SELECT STUFF('abcdef', 2, 3, 'ijklmn');

---------   
aijklmnef   

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If I dummy up the values and STUFF parameters into a subselect for demonstration purposes, here's how you can do it with SUBSTR.

```
SELECT
    substr(orig_string ,0,start_pos) 
    || replace_string || 
    substr(orig_string,start_pos+del_length, LENGTH(orig_string)) new_string,
    orig_string , replace_string
FROM
    (   SELECT
            'abcdef' orig_string ,
            2 start_pos ,
            3 del_length ,
            'ijklmn' replace_string ) foo
;
 NEW_STRING | ORIG_STRING | REPLACE_STRING 
------------+-------------+----------------
 aijklmnef  | abcdef      | ijklmn
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *GROUP_CONCAT* to achieve similar results as with *STUFF*. The *GROUP_CONCAT* function must installed from nzlua examples directory on the Netezza Linux environment.

```
export NZ_PASSWORD='YOURADMINPASSWORD'
cd /nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/examples
../bin/nzl group_concat.nzl
```

After this group_concat is available in Netezza *SYSTEM* database. As ADMIN you can execute these commands to make them easily available to all users in a database.

```
grant execute on system..group_concat(varchar(128)) to public; -- once
create synonym group_concat for system..group_concat; -- in every user database
```